# npm run dev failed with laravel 8 bootstrap and auth

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

I am using the laravel 8.x with laravel/ui package and bootstrap
here is my steps I've run in cmd:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

but it always returned this (at npm run dev' step):
'[npm run dev issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP9Iq.png)

> npm ERR! code ENOENT

> npm ERR! syscall spawn bash

> npm ERR! path C:\Work\testNPM

> npm ERR! errno -4058

> npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT

> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

> npm ERR! enoent

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Huy\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-12T07_10_08_779Z-debug-0.log

[The complete log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNlNb.png)

I have re-install mpn (rm node modules and package-lock.jsol) and re-install latest nodejs 18.5 but it doesn't work. Need your helps here.

Comment: It's odd that it's trying to spawn "bash" on a windows powershell environment. I'm not sure if bash is required to run mix on windows though I don't see anything in the documentation saying that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the answer:
go to file \Users\username\
look for and edit the file .npmrc then find the line which contains 'bash'. Delete that line and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have read there's an issue with vite currently (PHP 9.x). What you can try is paste this in your `package.json` file, and try again:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vite": "^2.9.11",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    },
    "name": "minicrm",
    "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></a></p>",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "vite.config.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "tests"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "acorn": "^8.7.1",
        "acorn-import-assertions": "^1.8.0",
        "ajv": "^6.12.6",
        "ajv-keywords": "^3.5.2",
        "anymatch": "^3.1.2",
        "binary-extensions": "^2.2.0",
        "braces": "^3.0.2",
        "browserslist": "^4.21.1",
        "buffer-from": "^1.1.2",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001363",
        "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
        "chrome-trace-event": "^1.0.3",
        "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
        "colorette": "^2.0.19",
        "commander": "^2.20.3",
        "cross-spawn": "^7.0.3",
        "electron-to-chromium": "^1.4.182",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^5.10.0",
        "envinfo": "^7.8.1",
        "es-module-lexer": "^0.9.3",
        "esbuild": "^0.14.48",
        "esbuild-darwin-arm64": "^0.14.48",
        "escalade": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-scope": "^5.1.1",
        "esrecurse": "^4.3.0",
        "estraverse": "^4.3.0",
        "events": "^3.3.0",
        "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
        "fast-json-stable-stringify": "^2.1.0",
        "fastest-levenshtein": "^1.0.12",
        "fill-range": "^7.0.1",
        "find-up": "^4.1.0",
        "follow-redirects": "^1.15.1",
        "fsevents": "^2.3.2",
        "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
        "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
        "glob-to-regexp": "^0.4.1",
        "graceful-fs": "^4.2.10",
        "has": "^1.0.3",
        "has-flag": "^4.0.0",
        "immutable": "^4.1.0",
        "import-local": "^3.1.0",
        "interpret": "^2.2.0",
        "is-binary-path": "^2.1.0",
        "is-core-module": "^2.9.0",
        "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
        "is-glob": "^4.0.3",
        "is-number": "^7.0.0",
        "is-plain-object": "^2.0.4",
        "isexe": "^2.0.0",
        "isobject": "^3.0.1",
        "jest-worker": "^27.5.1",
        "json-parse-even-better-errors": "^2.3.1",
        "json-schema-traverse": "^0.4.1",
        "kind-of": "^6.0.3",
        "klona": "^2.0.5",
        "loader-runner": "^4.3.0",
        "locate-path": "^5.0.0",
        "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
        "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
        "nanoid": "^3.3.4",
        "neo-async": "^2.6.2",
        "node-releases": "^2.0.5",
        "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
        "p-limit": "^2.3.0",
        "p-locate": "^4.1.0",
        "p-try": "^2.2.0",
        "path-exists": "^4.0.0",
        "path-key": "^3.1.1",
        "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
        "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
        "picomatch": "^2.3.1",
        "pkg-dir": "^4.2.0",
        "punycode": "^2.1.1",
        "randombytes": "^2.1.0",
        "readdirp": "^3.6.0",
        "rechoir": "^0.7.1",
        "resolve": "^1.22.1",
        "resolve-cwd": "^3.0.0",
        "resolve-from": "^5.0.0",
        "rollup": "^2.75.7",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
        "schema-utils": "^3.1.1",
        "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
        "shallow-clone": "^3.0.1",
        "shebang-command": "^2.0.0",
        "shebang-regex": "^3.0.0",
        "source-map": "^0.6.1",
        "source-map-js": "^1.0.2",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
        "supports-color": "^8.1.1",
        "supports-preserve-symlinks-flag": "^1.0.0",
        "tapable": "^2.2.1",
        "terser": "^5.14.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
        "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1",
        "update-browserslist-db": "^1.0.4",
        "uri-js": "^4.4.1",
        "watchpack": "^2.4.0",
        "webpack": "^5.73.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
        "webpack-sources": "^3.2.3",
        "which": "^2.0.2",
        "wildcard": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Does Laravel 8.x use vite?

Comment: @brombeer yeppp

Comment: More like "nope". Laravel8 uses webpack/Mix, Laravel9 uses vite

Comment: ah my bad, thought we were talking about 9. yep 8 uses webpack/mix js ;)

Comment: It doesn't for my Laravel 8 projects. Because its using Mix. btw, thank you.